# Waiting for coordinates to be found before making POST

Tags: swift, wait

I am using CLGeocoder to get the coordinates of the address entered by the user which will be sent to the server. But this function which is called before the POST to the server takes so long that the server has already been sent the information and has replied before the coordinates are found. How do I wait for this function to finish and notify the method that called it that it can proceed?

```
func getCoordinates(address: String){

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

         geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            self.lat = String(format: "%f",(placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
            self.lon = String(format: "%f",(placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

            print("Lat: \(self.lat), Lon: \(self.lon)")
        })

}
```

I have looked at UNUserNotificationCenter and DispatchGroup but to no avail...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot ways to do this. For example you call [Swift Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) after retrieving coordinates.

```
func getCoordinates(address: String, completionHandler:()->()){

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

        let placemark = placemarks?.first
        self.lat = String(format: "%f",(placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
        self.lon = String(format: "%f",(placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

        print("Lat: \(self.lat), Lon: \(self.lon)")
        completionHandler() //call Swift Closure after retrieving coordinates.
    })

}

//USAGE
getCoordinates(address: "address",
               completionHandler:{
                print("Lat: \(self.lat), Lon: \(self.lon)")
                //execute POST query here <===
})
```